# How to delete the text within brackets using re.compile and re.findall?

Tags: python, regex, list, beautifulsoup

I want to delete the text between brackets(including the brackets). This text is stored in lists. I would also like to store the output text(without brackets in a new list).

**I tried using:**

```
es = ["49,331,076","23,136,275","139,500 (est.)","124,000","522 (ranked 23 of 137)"]
length=len(es)
regex = re.compile(".*?\((.*?)\)")
for x in range(length):
    listy.append(re.findall(regex, es[p]))
    p=p+1
```

But, this will return the text between the brackets.

**expected results:**

```
"[49,331,076, 23,136,275, 139,500, 124,000, 522]"
```

**The results I got:**

```
"[], [], [est.], [u'ranked 18 of 137']"
```

Comment: do you know the theorie that regex can not handle multiple nested brackets?

Comment: Why is the answer unaccepted? Do you need more help? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `re.sub` with a `\([^()]*\)` pattern:

```
import re
es = ["49,331,076","23,136,275","139,500 (est.)","124,000","522 (ranked 23 of 137)"]
regex = re.compile(r"\([^()]*\)")
listy = []
for x in es:
    listy.append(regex.sub('', x).strip())
# Or, instead of the two lines above use a list comprehension:
# listy = [regex.sub('', x).strip() for x in es]
print(listy) # => ['49,331,076', '23,136,275', '139,500', '124,000', '522']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9TntMB)

Note it is easier to loop over list items with `for x in es:`, no need to get its length and then track the current item with a counter. It is even more Pythonic to use a list comprehension, `[regex.sub('', x).strip() for x in es]`.

The `\([^()]*\)` pattern matches `(`, then any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`. If there can be `(` in between, use `\(.*?\)` or `\([^)]*\)`.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple loop incrementing a counter when `(` is found, decrementing when `)` is found, and when the counter is zero again, delete substring, be better ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do a `sub()` with the matches:

```
import re
es = ["49,331,076","23,136,275","139,500 (est.)","124,000","522 (ranked 23 of 137)"]

length=len(es)
regex = re.compile("\(.+\)")
cleaned_es = [regex.sub('', val) for val in es]
print(cleaned_es)
```

You can also throw in a `strip()` just to remove any trailing white spaces:

```
cleaned_es = [regex.sub('', val).strip() for val in es]
```

Which will give you:

```
['49,331,076', '23,136,275', '139,500', '124,000', '522']
```